# HERE Api - Daily limit of requests has been reached - but on plan description doesn't mention that

Tags: error-handling, limit, here-api

I recently subscribed on HERE Api for Freemium account, cause as far as I understood, I could make 250k requests per month and only would be charged after that, recently I'm working on Waypoints Sequence, and suddenly during a dev test, I got the error "Daily limit of 10 requests has been reached".

I thought that the limit was 250k requests per month, but then I read that the user can only make 10 requests per day by App ID, but makes no sense when the month limit is significantly higher.

Out of Freemium Account there's only the Pro/Premier Plans, which are actually very expensive for me right now.

Does anyone have a workaround for this? Or have another "Waypoints Sequence" tool to recomend?

Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, for Freemium plans only, the following limits apply:

- Custom Locations: you may upload a maximum of 3 layers with a maximum of 100 polygons or polylines.
- Waypoints Sequence: up to 10 requests per day.
- Advanced Data Sets: up to 100 requests per hour and 1,000 per day.

Please contact our Sales team ([Contact Sales](https://developer.here.com/help#how-can-we-help-you)) if you want to raise your limits. Thank you.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, I already used the contact form to know if there's a plan that fit our company. For now I'm just waiting for they to respond me, thank you very much!